# Poor performance for OR condition involving multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.AId = B.AId
WHERE A.ADate BETWEEN @Start and @End
     or B.BDate BETWEEN @Start and @End
```

Both tables A and B are about the same size and have a lot of rows.  Execution plan shows a index seek, but looks like it is scanning the entire index.

If I change the `or` to `and` then the query is very fast.  I think this is due to the fact that the result of the `or` cannot be known without performing a table scan on both tables to compute the `or`.  The `and` is easily split into two operations.

I have read some people stating that it is possible to use `UNION` in place of `or`, but this would potentially introduce duplicate rows in the case that both conditions in the OR are true.

What solution is there so that I can reduce the size of join and prevent a full join of both tables? I am open to restructuring the query however possible to make this work, but need the logic of the query(give me items where either the date in a matches the range or the date in B matches the range) to remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, in the end I opted for `UNION ALL`, and I crafted a query based on the union of two selects that are mutually exclusive, so no duplicates would be introduced in the `UNION ALL`.

First, get all the rows where `ADate` is in the range, and exclude rows where `BDate` is in the range. Then get all the rows where `BDate` is in the range.  The union of these two sets logically produces the set of rows that covers `ADate` or `BDate`, without double counting the middle(so a `UNION ALL` will not produce duplicates). Let me know if you see a flaw in this logic, I found it helpful to think of a venn diagram.

This made the query perform the best of the options presented(in my case), and wasn't overly complicated, so I went with it.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.AId = B.AId
WHERE A.ADate BETWEEN @Start and @End
   and B.BDate NOT BETWEEN @Start and @End

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.AId = B.AId
WHERE B.BDate BETWEEN @Start and @End
```

Perhaps this could be a query optimization for the `OR` operator in some scenarios, especially when querying separate, large tables, it works with date ranges, but could work with any other predicates I imagine.

Answer (score 2):

What about pre-filtering each table before you join using inline tables:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM (SELECT AId AS Id FROM A WHERE A.ADate BETWEEN @Start and @End
      UNION
      SELECT BId AS Id FROM B WHERE B.BDate BETWEEN @Start and @End) AS FilteredIds
INNER JOIN A ON A.AId = FilteredIds.Id
INNER JOIN B ON B.BId = FilteredIds.Id
```

Comment: Wouldn't that alter the logic?

Comment: @Kekoa how has the logic changed?

Comment: I changed my logic a bit - (Chris my pre-filtering was acting more like the AND that he didn't want).  Now I'm doing a Union as well, but not retrieving the full row until we've filtered down.  Might be faster than the union directly over everything.

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` will not introduce duplicate rows.  A `UNION ALL` could introduce duplicates.

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

I'd imagine that:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.AId = B.AId
WHERE A.ADate BETWEEN @Start and @End

UNION

SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.AId = B.AId
WHERE B.BDate BETWEEN @Start and @End
```

could be a faster query.

Comment: Thanks for the correction about UNION, I will try it out. I'm a bit worried about the distinct sort that it does to ensure no duplicates though, but it may be faster than the `or` behavior I am seeing.

Comment: Sure. If it doesn't perform well, have a stab at Mike Parkhill's approach- that may be rather faster.